# Codeigntier Active Record Join

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

Codeigniter's active record doesn't seem to be fetching all my rows when I attempt a JOIN LEFT.

DB Setup (simplified)

```
Things                                        Likes
----------------------------------------     ---------------------------
|  thing_id  |   thing_name |  user_id |     | thing_id   |   user_id  |
----------------------------------------     ---------------------------
|     1      |    Thing 1   |   5555   |     |    2       |    6666    |
|     2      |    Thing 2   |   5555   |     |    3       |    7777    |
|     3      |    Thing 3   |   5555   |     ---------------------------
|     4      |    Thing 4   |   5555   |
----------------------------------------
```

When I fetch the list by user_id against the 'things' table, I get the expected result of 4.

```
  $sql = $this->db->where('things.user_id', $user_id)->get('things')->result();
```

But when I do this, I get 3 (things 2, 3 & 4).

```
  $sql = $this->db->select('things.thing_id as thing_id, COUNT(likes.thing_id) as likes')
                    ->where("things.user_id", $user_id)
                    ->from('things')
                    ->join('likes', 'things.thing_id = likes.thing_id', 'LEFT')
                    ->group_by('likes.thing_id')
                    ->get()
                    ->result();
```

I'm confused because it does grab 1 'thing' that is not in the 'like' table, but not the other, so I'm confused on if it is a JOIN fail, or something else.

**Solved: By switching GROUP BY from 'likes.thing_id' to 'things.thing_id'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by switching `GROUP BY` from `likes.thing_id` to `things.thing_id`.

My result of 3 items was a result of being grouped as `Thing 2`, `Thing 3` and `NULL`, which the 2 items not in the `likes` table were being grouped as.